# Find Pearson correlation coefficients from the Linear regression coefficients

Tags: regression, correlation

I am trying to simulate transition from the linear regression coefficients to the Pearson correlation coefficients.

I have these two equalities:

$r_i= \beta_i \times \frac{standardDeviation(X_i)}{standardDeviation(Y)}$

and

$\beta_i =\frac{covariance(X_i,Y)}{variance(X_i)}$,

where $X_i$ are independent variables or features in the model and $Y$ is a dependent variable, which we are trying to predict.

What I want to do is to check the correspondance between rescaled linear coefficients of the multiple regression problem and Pearson's correlations. For this reason I've wrote the following code in Python, which generates a random point cloud $X$, where each point (except last one) is an indepent variable and a single (last) point in the matrix $X[-1,:]$ is the dependent variable $Y$.

```
import numpy as np
# create uncorrelated random data 
X = np.random.rand(n, m)
```

Next step is a covariance matrix  $Cov(X)$ calculation:

```
Omega = np.cov(X)
```

Shape of the Omega should be $(n,n)$.

Next step is to find correlation matrix from the covariance matrix Omega. For this purpose I wrote next function:

```
def correlation_from_covariance(covariance):
   v = np.sqrt(np.diag(covariance))
   outer_v = np.outer(v, v)
   correlation = covariance / outer_v
   correlation[covariance == 0] = 0
   return correlation
```

and

```
Corr = correlation_from_covariance(Omega)
```

For now, we have all possible $r_{i,j}$ for any variable combinations and we need no chose single dependent variable $Y$ from all $X$. Suppose that

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

Y = X[-1, :].T   #np.shape(Y) = (m, 1)
X_lr = X[:-1,:]  #np.shape(X_lr) = (n-1, m)

indices = np.random.permutation(len(X_lr))
step = (len(X_un)//100)*80

X_train = X_lr[indices[:step]]
Y_train = Y[indices[:step]]
X_test = X_lr[indices[step:]]
Y_test = Y[indices[step:]]

reg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, Y_train)
coefficients = reg.coef_  #np.shape(coefficients) = np.shape(Y) = (m, 1)
```

Now we have linear coefficients of the Linear Regression and can compare them with the Corr elements, which are corresponding to correlations between $X_i$ and $Y$. For this reason let's implement first formula in Python:

```
  def coeff_to_corr(coefficients, X, y): 
      corr = np.zeros(len(coefficients),)
      for i in range(len(coefficients)): 
          corr[i] = coefficients[i] * (np.std(X[i,:]) / np.std(y) )

      return corr

  corr = coeff_to_corr(coefficients, X_lr, Y)

  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  plt.scatter(abs(Corr[-1,:]), abs(np.array(corr)))
  plt.show()
```

But for n = m = 101 I don't have a linear correspondance between correlation coefficients and correlations obtained as the rescaled versions of the regression coefficients.

[image]

Comment: You seem to be trying to apply formulas for a single regressor to a multiple regression problem.  I lost you at "we need no chose single dependent variable Y from all X," because I cannot relate that to your question and you are relying on people to understand your code in order to read your question -- but since your code doesn't do what you expect, that's not an effective way to express yourself!  Could you rewrite your question in English?

Comment: @whuber yes, thank you for the comment, a few minutes

Comment: @whuber by the way, you are saying about formulas from a multiple regression problem. . I think the core problem is here, I didn't know there are different formulas for single and multiple regression problems and thought that any linear coefficient from the multiple problem could be found using the first equality in the question. If so, maybe you can give me a proper formula for the multiple regression problem?

Comment: Multiple regression coefficients always differ from the univariate regressions except for regressors that are orthogonal to the rest.  For formulas and discussions, please [see this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=multiple+regression+coefficient+formula).

Comment: @whuber so it is impossible to do directly for a multiple regression case as in my exaple? Or there are solutions?

Comment: It depends on what correlations you want.  If you're doing multiple regression, then the simple bivariate correlations are practically meaningless, but you should be able to recover them from the coefficients *and* the covariance matrix of the regressors (generalizing the ordinary regression formulas you quote).

Comment: @whuber why is it meaningless? I thought to use it to check, that the multiple regression made correctly and the coefficients correspond to the Pearson's correlations obtained directly for the pairs of (independent, dependent) variables

Comment: But that interpretation is incorrect.  Indeed, the reason we do multiple regression is precisely because it's so very wrong!

Comment: @whuber thank you, can you please recommend a textbook where I can read all this things?

Comment: Any good second (post-intro) textbook on regression will cover them.  One (older) book that emphasizes the differences between multiple and ordinary regression is Mosteller & Tukey, *Data Analysis and Regression: A Second Course in Statistics.*  A *very* large number of threads here on CV discuss all kinds of nuances: link through the [multiple-regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-regression) tag and read some of the highest-voted answers to get a sense of what's here.